# Simulation software for AOCS/GNC?

Tags: spacecraft, attitude, software

I would like to know what are the simulation software tools available as of today (free or commercial) to perform some attitude and orbit control (AOC) or guidance and navigation control analysis, I am mostly interested in testing some attitude control algorithms.

So far I found two that maybe could be useful, do you know any others?

- psatellite: Spacecraft Control Toolbox.
- 42 (open source)

Does anyone had any experience with these software? Can you give me any suggestions?

Comment: MATLAB is always pretty good for orbit and attitude simulations

Comment: I used 42 to simulate new attitude control algorithms for my undergraduate thesis. I might have some resources/sample code if you want more info.

Comment: Late to the party, but: do MATLAB solvers have the numerical precision needed for orbital simulations? I always thought you needed special solvers for this sort of thing.

Comment: The latest one is Basilisk. It is an astrodynamics software developed at the University of Colorado, Boulder. It is also open-source. Link: http://hanspeterschaub.info/basilisk/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of great open-source tools available for that including NASA's [Trick](https://github.com/nasa/trick) library. I did an internship at NASA where Trick was heavily utilized for GN&C software-in-the-loop and hardware-in-the-loop scenarios.

There is also [Cesium](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium) for 3D visualization of your model and physics.

Comment: Cool. I didn't know Trick was public. Thanks for posting.

Comment: Happy to help! NASA has a massive collection of open-source software at https://code.nasa.gov/